# Java Sqlite Database connection in another pc

Tags: java

Does anyone know how its possible to access  sqlite database on another computer . which is on the same network as the computer having the database itself using a java application?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is not designed to be used by multiple clients at the same time. 
Ignoring this will cause concurrency issues when accesing the db. In such case the SQLite developers recommend to choose another database for this work.

Answer (score 2):

An `SQLite` database is only accessible via a pathname.  Being stored on a computer in the same network is not enough; that computer would additionally need to share the directory containing the database file, so that a filesystem path to the database can exist.

And, as tak3shi mentioned, SQLite is not designed for simultaneous access by multiple clients, so "sharing" the database can lead to other issues.